# Why does my code output nothing to the console?

Tags: .net, vb.net, loops

I have the following array through which I loop and output the result to the console. Although I see nothing wrong with it, the output is empty:

```
Module Module1

Sub Main()

    Dim Fields As New List(Of Tuple(Of Integer, String, List(Of Tuple(Of Integer, String)))) From {
        Tuple.Create(1000124, "A", New List(Of Tuple(Of Integer, String)) From { 
            Tuple.Create(1038231, "A1"), 
            Tuple.Create(1038232, "A2"),
            Tuple.Create(1038233, "A3"),
            Tuple.Create(1038234, "A4")
        }),
        Tuple.Create(1000152, "B", New List(Of Tuple(Of Integer, String)) From { 
            Tuple.Create(1078247, "B1"),
            Tuple.Create(1078248, "B2"),
            Tuple.Create(1078250, "B3"),
            Tuple.Create(1078251, "B4"),
            Tuple.Create(1078253, "B5")
        })
    }

    For Each parent In Fields
        Console.WriteLine("[{0}] {1}", parent.Item1, parent.Item2)

        For Each child In parent.Item3
            Console.WriteLine("    [{0}] {1}", child.Item1, child.Item2)
        Next
    Next

    Console.Read()

End Sub

End Module
```

I have been staring at this for hours but cannot see what I am doing wrong. Can you?

Comment: When I paste this code into LINQPad, I do get the expected output. Where/how are you trying to see that output?

Comment: Visual Studio 2012...weird?!

Comment: How are you running it? Is it a console application? Are you by any chance referring to the "Output" window in Visual Studio? (cause that won't display `Console.WriteLine()` IIRC)

Comment: Did you compile it as a Windows application instead of a Console application? (This is an assembly setting.) Windows applications do not write to the console.

Comment: Hint for the next time: when you cannot see it by staring at something, stare somewhere else :-)

Comment: ..after ten years of .NET development, I just now learn that Console.Writeline will do an implicit String.Format with parameter substitution.  *weeps*